# Annotation processing in not supported for module cycles

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

[Build output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U10CF.png)

I am trying to build my project, but as there exists the circular dependency through the pom.xml file, i can't build my project.

I have tried using @Lazy, but it is not working because the Pom.xml file for the package gets compiled first, and the error comes during the build.

Comment: Please copy-paste plain text instead of image